# Dji mavic air 2 "remote controller not connected" when trying to connect to aircraft

Tags: flight-controller, dji-mavic-air-2

So i just updated my drone to the new firmware and when i tried to start up my drone i kept getting a message saying that the remote controller isn't connected. Both batteries are full and i tried a different smartphone to see if that would help and still nothing. The drone is in great condition so it's nothing that i can really pinpoint other than updating to the new firmware. Every tutorial says to click on connect to aircraft but i can't get past that because it says remote controller not connected.

Comment: Have you tried another cable between the phone and the controller?